# Getting 404 Error in my nextjs13 API-Route

Tags: node.js, rest, next.js

I forked a project and want to setup a API Endpoint for my CRUD operations with a DB, but I can't even access my endpoint. I tried it with a dummy API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos And Still getting 404 When I want to access my endpoint.

**pages > api > todo > route.js
**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


const DATA_SOURCE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"

export async function GET() {
    const res = await fetch(DATA_SOURCE_URL)

    const todos = await res.json

    return NextResponse.json(todos)
}
```

**my project
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpxzk.png)

I have no middleware setup that could block this Endpoint. I am wondering where this error occures.

I have also tried creating a brand new Next.js 13 app, and when I created the endpoint there, it worked, and I received a 200 status code.

**default nextjs project
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOPnw.png)

Here files:

**package.json
**

```
{
  "name": "ship-fast-code",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "postbuild": "next-sitemap",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/mongodb-adapter": "^1.0.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.17",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "crisp-sdk-web": "^1.0.21",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "mailgun.js": "^9.2.1",
    "micro": "^10.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.8.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.4",
    "next": "^13.4.12",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.1",
    "next-sitemap": "^4.2.2",
    "nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.16",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^5.21.1",
    "stripe": "^13.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "daisyui": "^3.6.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

**next.config.js
**

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      // NextJS <Image> component needs to whitelist domains for src={}
      "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
      "pbs.twimg.com",
      "images.unsplash.com",
      "logos-world.net",
      'dlcdnwebimgs.asus.com',
      'res-1.cloudinary.com',
      'avatars.githubusercontent.com'
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**jsconfig.json
**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

_document.js

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import config from "@/config";


export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en" data-theme={config.colors.theme}>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content={config.colors.main} />
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content={config.colors.main} />

        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon"
          sizes="180x180"
          href="/apple-touch-icon.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          sizes="32x32"
          href="/favicon-32x32.png"
        />
        <link
          rel="icon"
          type="image/png"
          sizes="16x16"
          href="/favicon-16x16.png"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

        <script
          defer
          data-domain={config.domainName}
          src="https://plausible.io/js/script.js"
        ></script>
      </Head>
      <body>

        <Main />
        <NextScript />

      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}
```

I think there is something blocking the Endpoint in my project

Answer (score 1):

In the image you have posted, you are accessing `api/todos` instead of `api/todo`. The endpoint should be something like `http://localhost:3000/api/todo` by the looks of your directories. Try if that helps, if not try debugging using `console.log()`